# How do I stop my .htaccess file causing a recursive redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using the following .htaccess to redirect my query to fcgi scriptI get a recursive redirect problem. Can anyone suggest what needs tweaking?

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^answers.mynewdomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://answers.mynewdomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ osqa.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: How do you test this? Is it possible that you’re using a client that only supports HTTP 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to escape the dots?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^answers\.mynewdomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
```